# A counterexample when $\text{char}(\mathbb{F})=2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

When trying to prove this:

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
        A & B \\
        B & A 
        \end{bmatrix}=\det(A+B)\det(A-B),$$

for $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ when  $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, I used the fact that $\text{char}(\mathbb{F})\neq 2$ because at the end of the proof, after a few calculations both side of que equation above have an extra factor $2^n$ (if you want, I can post it). This fact made me look for a counterexample when the characteristic of the field is $=2$. There is such counterexample? If not, how to prove this statement for any field? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the first $n$ rows to the last $n$ rows and then adding the negative of the last $n$ columns to the first $n$ columns we obtain via the formula for a triangular matrix per blocks:

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
        A & B \\
        B & A 
        \end{bmatrix}=\det\begin{bmatrix}
        A & B \\
        A+B & A+B 
        \end{bmatrix}=\det\begin{bmatrix}
        A-B & B \\
        0 & A+B 
        \end{bmatrix}=\det(A+B)\det(A-B).$$ So the hypothesis of $F$ be a field can be reduced to merely a commutative ring.

Answer (score 2):

Both sides of the equation above are polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[A_{ij}, B_{ij}]$, where $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$ are the entries of $A$ and $B$, respectively. If they agree over characteristic $p\not = 2$, then they also agree in characteristic $2$.

Comment: Why? Isn't clear for me.

Comment: @Jccalab Do you understand that both sides of the equation are polynomials in $\mathbb Z[A_{ij}, B_{ij}]$? If you treat these polynomials as functions on $\mathbb R^{2n^2}$, then their coefficients can be extracted using partial derivatives. (There are more general theorems of this nature that are more purely algebraic in nature, but I think this line of reasoning that uses Calculus is a good start for understanding it.)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Yes, I underestand, but still don't see why. And Is not the kind of argument I looking for because is out of the approach of the course I've taken.

Comment: @Jccalab Can you please be more specific about what it is you don't understand?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think that I got the proof. Gonna post it.